# XSL count based on conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have XML data similar to the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Database>
    <ResultsStore>
        <Result Type="A">
            <Info Value="3" />
        </Result>
        <Result Type="B">
            <Info Value="0" />
        </Result>
        <Result Type="C">
            <Info Value="1" />
        </Result>
    </ResultsStore>

    <ResultsStore>
        <Result Type="A">
            <Info Value="3" />
        </Result>
        <Result Type="B">
            <Info Value="0" />
        </Result>
        <Result Type="C">
            <Info Value="0" />
        </Result>
    </ResultsStore>

    <ResultsStore>
        <Result Type="A">
            <Info Value="3" />
        </Result>
        <Result Type="B">
            <Info Value="1" />
        </Result>
        <Result Type="C">
            <Info Value="1" />
        </Result>
    </ResultsStore>

    <!-- etc. -->
</Database>
```

I need to count the number of ResultsStores that have either Result B or Result C with a non-zero Info Value. In the above code example, the count should be 2 for the three ResultsStores.

I have written the following code, but it gives the incorrect value of 3 since it does not only count B or C once:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="results_stores_count">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(Database/ResultsStore/Result[@Type='A' or @Type='B']/Info[not(@Value=0)]) />
</xsl:variable>
```

Any help or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> count the number of ResultsStores that have either Result B or Result C with a non-zero Info Value.

If you want to count ResultsStores, then don't count Results. Also, if you want to count types B and C, then don't count types A and B.

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(Database/ResultsStore[Result[@Type='B']/Info/@Value!=0 or Result[@Type='C']/Info/@Value!=0]) "/>
```

Comment: Alternative xpath: `count(Database/ResultsStore[Result[@Type='B' or @Type='C']/Info[not(@Value='0')]])`

Comment: This works like a charm! I'm new to XSL, so I wasn't aware you could do conditionals like that. Thank you.